[145007:JC_ILLEGAL_SYMBOL_CHARACTER while saving : charecter in griddb
I'm trying to use ':' for tag values, I need store characters ':' in griddb, and facing this issue [145007:JC_ILLEGAL_SYMBOL_CHARACTER, is there any way to store this?
I'm trying to use ':' for tag values in griddb and facing an error

Cluster names, container names, and other identifiers can now include a wider range of characters, including alphanumeric characters, underscores (_), hyphens (-), dots (.), slashes (/), and equals signs (=). However, colons (:) are still not permitted.
Identifiers can now include alphanumeric characters, _, -, ., /, and =, but not :.
https://github.com/griddb/griddb_nosql/blob/master/docs/GridDB-4.0-CE-RELEASE_NOTES.md
Please follow this link to get clarity.
